# Google APIs Get User Email PHP

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api

I'm using Google plus API in my website to Sign In users and it does work great, However because I only need the user email since I create my own `Auth Token` I no longer need to use Google plus API because Gmail API provide all the information I need Also give more `daily query` Which is `1,000,000,000` compared to `20,000,000` for Google plus API.

**The Problem is:**

When I used Gmail API I got the same information that Google plus API provided, Which is great.

[image]

**However**, going to my dashboard inside `Google Cloud Console >> OAuth consent screen Tap >> OAuth rate limits`.

It says that `Your token grant rate = Your current per day token grant rate limit is 10,000 grants per day. The per day token grant rate resets every day`

[image]

**So**, Do I miss something?

> Note: When I switched to Gmail API, I did change the `client key`, `secret key`, and `Google Sign In URL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the [OAuth Rate Limits](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9028764?hl=en) and the [Gmail API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota). When designing your app you have two take into consideration these two factors:

#### 1) OAuth

The [OAuth Rate Limits](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9028764?hl=en) refers to the number of tokens that your application can request to Google in order to be able to have permission to sensitive scopes from the users that are utilizing your app and in that way allow to access their data (how much data depends in the scopes) when calling the Gooogle's APIs.

#### 2) Gmail API

The [Gmail API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota) refers to the number of requests that your app can do to the API, no matter the number of users(as long as it doesn't surpass the limit) because it was previously checked by the OAuth rate limit.

Comment: Thank you, this is my first time working with Google API and It's a little bit confusing,
one last thing though, you referenced `Gmail API Usage Limits`, and I can't find  if there's Google plus API Usage Limits, Do you have a link for that?

Comment: You're welcome! There is no longer more support to the Google Plus API, therefore I would recommend you to keep using the Gmail API.